# Canada Low Cost Airline

Tags: air-travel, canada, airlines, low-cost-carriers, yvr

Are there any low cost airlines that operate within Canada and fly out of Vancouver? As a European I have very limited knowledge of flying within the US and Canada.

I am struggling to find any, unless I am looking in the wrong places.

EDIT: Have checked Skycanner and the cheapest options between Vancouver and Toronto are all national carriers (or seem to be) and certainly not I would class as budget. Where are the £29.99 flights? (sarcasm) Is budget a thing in North America? Or does the vast distances involved stop any budget airline from operating like in Europe?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use a comparison site (ITA, Skyscanner, Kayak etc) and pick the cheapest option, "low cost" or not?

Comment: Skyscanner cheapest flights are all national carriers and not low cost budget airlines @CMaster

Comment: Canada is bigger than you think. Even if you think it's big. Vancouver to Toronto is 4500km. You will not find a £29.99 flight between two cities in Europe that far apart, for the simple reason that there are no cities in Europe that far apart. Also both those cities are fairly small by European standards, Carriers aren't able to make their profit on volume.

Comment: Well, if the cheapest tickets are flag carriers, then it doesn't really matter if low cost carriers are available or not, does it?

Comment: If you consider [Bellingham (BLI)](http://www.bellingham-airport.com) to be "Vancouver", then there is [Allegiant](http://www.allegiantair.com). (Be sure to pay attention to all the [fees](http://www.allegiantair.com/popup/optional-services-fees)!)

Comment: But, vis-a-vis what @200_success suggests, be aware that Bellingham is in Washington state. I have no idea what visa requirements apply to the OP, but there may be issues with crossing the border.

Comment: In North America, 100 years is a long time.  In Europe, 100 miles (or km) is a long distance.

Comment: Low-cost carriers were _invented_ in North America, though specifically in the USA. Southwest Airlines is the world's largest low-cost carrier, according to Wikipedia; there are plenty of others in the US, such as jetBlue and Frontier.

Comment: @MichaelT I'm not seeing the relevance. The question is asked by a European who doesn't seem to have noticed that 4500km is a long distance. Anyone who's flying probably isn't considering distances around the 100mi/km mark.

Comment: @DavidRicherby A search suggested a flight from London to Edinburgh is in the  £29.99 range.  Its ~400 miles and that's nearly all the way across the country. Many times Europeans don't realize how *big* North America is (and 400 miles isn't that far of a distance for me... that's driving half way across the state I live in, doing some repairs and driving back... shoot, I used to drive ~90 miles one way to get a good dinner when I lived in the northern part of Wisconsin). The bit is a hint at the completely different scales of the countries in terms of history and distance.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think Michael's point was mostly just a reiteration of DJClayworth's point. Canada is _really big_. The entire U.K. fits inside Vancouver's single province... almost 4 times. The distances involved are the primary reason for the higher prices. It's hard to find a 30 pound fare on flight that is over 2,000 miles regardless of what continent you're on. Vancouver to Toronto is about the same distance as Madrid to Moscow.

Comment: Some flights with somewhat similar distances to Vancouver-Toronto, all can be found for $50-75: London-Istanbul, Budapest-Dubai, Geneva-Tel Aviv. Flying is indeed more expensive in Canada, even despite it being a a long distance. You'll never find Toronto-Montreal for $15, even though you'll find flights to a plethora of destinations a similar distance from London in Central Europe for that price.

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, I know that Canada is extremely big. I know you're not going to be able to fly acros a continent for thirty quid. And I'm still failing to see the relevance of pointing out that Europeans think that a hundred miles is a long way, in a situation where the problem is that a European hasn't realised that _three thousand_ miles is a long way! "Europeans think 100 miles is a long way" means that Europeans are wary of journeys that North Americans think are fairly short. We're in the exact opposite situation to that: a European not understanding why a very long journey is expensive.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is to put it into perspective. I've talked to a British man who was blown away that the ***entire history of the country*** can be read in news papers.  100 years takes you half way across the history of Canada or United States.  100 miles takes you half way across the width of a European country.  The challenge is that when you look at a map of North America or England, you don't see the scale at the bottom (I also talked to a British woman who asked if it was possible to bike from San Francisco to New Orleans in a few days before realizing the scales were different).

Comment: @MichaelT "100 miles takes you half way across the width of a European country." \*sigh\* Now you're making exactly the opposite mistake. Norway and Sweden are about a thousand miles from north to south. Ukraine is over 800 from east to west. Spain and France are more than 600 miles across; the UK's about 600 miles from north to south; Italy's 650. The European Union as a whole is a little over half the size of the contiguous 48 states of the US. It's not some tiny place.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm exaggerating a little bit. The horizontal width of England and Wales is 271 miles.  France is about 600 miles x 600 miles.  Germany is 400 miles by 500 miles.  However, I'd also be happy to talk about the dimensions of Switzerland or Liechtenstein or Austria or Hungry or Albania or Macedonia pr Belgium or the Netherlands or or Luxembourg or Denmark or Andorra or Greece too.  There is a different scale of thought when you can drive from Los Angeles to Redding (550 miles) and *still* be in the California and another hour to go before you get to  Oregon.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Or, to compare with Canada, my province (Saskatchewan) is bigger than France, or Ukraine, or Spain (the three biggest in Europe proper); and it is, by area, eighth among Canada's provinces and territories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there are not currently any really low cost airlines in Canada. But there seem to be a few in the pipeline:

- [**NewLeaf**](http://action.flynewleaf.ca/): It looks like Abbotsford near Vancouver is one of their anticipated destinations, but they are running into a [bit of bureaucracy](http://action.flynewleaf.ca/NewLeaf-Jan19MediaRelease.pdf).
- [**JetLines**](http://www.jetlines.ca/): "Canada’s Ultra-Low Fare Airline" currently completed planning and development. Based in Vancouver.
- [**Jet Naked**](http://centreforaviation.com/profiles/airlines/jet-naked): Not sure if they plan to fly out of Vancouver.

[WestJet](http://www.westjet.com) and [Air Canada Rouge](http://www.aircanada.com/en/about/media/rouge/) are I think currently generally the lowest cost airlines in Canada but they are not really budget airlines.

Answer (score 8):

There are several lower cost airlines already operating in Canada, but no  ULCCs on par with Ryanair. In eastern Canada, where distances are shorter there tends to be more competition, here are the airlines on these routes:

- Toronto-Montreal: Air Canada, Porter, WestJet, Transat from ca$99
- [Vancouver-Toronto](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=YVR;t=YYZ,YTZ;d=2016-06-17;r=2016-06-21;tt=o): Air Canada, WestJet, [Sunwing](http://www.sunwing.ca/Canada-Travel/cheap-flights-in-canada.asp?optGateway=YVR) (in summer) from ca$249

Elsewhere in North America you'll find your $29 flights. As you say, "is budget not a thing North America?" Canada isn't all of North America. Budget / ULCC airlines are a thing in the US and Mexico (Spirit, Frontier, Volaris, Vivaaerobus, Interjet, Vivacolombia to Florida, Norwegian from the US to the EU parts of the Caribbean...). Spirit and Allegiant specifically serve airports close to major Canadian cities (for instance Niagra Falls New York for Toronto, Plattsburgh New York for Montreal, Bellingham Washington for Vancouver) but mostly for flights to further south in the US and not east-west connections.

Comment: $249 Vancouver Toronto is cheaper per km than £29 London Paris

Comment: @DJClayworth Ah, whoops, you're right. I missed the different currencies.